# How can I add some "space before" spacing to a single line of text inside a table cell of 5 lines of text

Tags: html, css, html-table

If I use CSS line-height property on a span element to adjust for particular lines I get the extra space before the line in questions but cannot reset to regular line spacing with a follow up CSS class. In table shown below see bottom right cell. Before "Tokyo:" I want extra 'space-before' and after "Tokyo:" I want regular line spacing to return.

```css
td span.hard_line_break {
    line-height: 2em;
}

td span.soft_line_break {
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr class="table_top row_color_A">
      <td class="bold_type td"><a href="/pdf/Terra-Publica-2014-04-Half-Day_Courses.pdf">Encroachments onto Council-Controlled Land</a></td>
      <td class="td">Councils, both urban and rural, must address encroachments on reserves, roads and lanes.</td>
      <td class="td">Brisbane:<br />Friday 23 May<br />9am&mdash;12:30pm<br />
        <span class="hard_line_break">Tokyo:</span>
        <span class="soft_line_break"><br />Tuesday 20 May</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Entire table HTML/CSS to see and interact with:
http://jsfiddle.net/wideEyedPupil/3LeS6/1/

Line-height feels like it's the wrong property but can't get padding/margins to work on span elements inside a table cell. What is the proper way to do this please?

[image: /]

---

EDIT:
Okay I have it working using suggestion of div tags.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wideEyedPupil/3LeS6/7/)**

[image: as it should display]

[image: /]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem but looks like you just need to increase the line-height?

Comment: Get rid of all `<br />`. Turn `span`s to `div`s, and apply proper `margin-top` to `div`s that you want a little space before them.

Comment: "Line-height feels like it's the wrong property " why?

Comment: @web-tiki: Line height specifies the height of one line of text. If you have longer text that spans two or more lines you will have unnecessary gaps between those lines as well.

Comment: @SalmanA true, but it doesn't seem to be the case for the OP as he only has one word in the `span` element. That is why I was asking.

Comment: @web-tiki for a start line height doesn't reset to normal on the next line "Tuesday 20 May"

Comment: I tried using <p> tags and a td p {margin:…} CSS element but it inserted (unwanted) space before the first line. Will go the div route. I'm yet to grok divs, especially when it comes to mutliple floats and clears.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil ok I understand you issue, Salman A's solution should  suit you

Answer (score 1):

Do u mean something like this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3LeS6/4/)

As u can see, maybe adding a `css` could help you

UPDATE:

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3LeS6/6/)

Comment: I guess he wants a little space before Tokyo but not after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
.hard_line_break {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

And get rid of the `<br>` before and after it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/3LeS6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put two `<br /><br />` tags before `Tokyo` and get rid of those `<span>` tags. It's the easiest solution I can think of.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for something with more subtle spatial control.